# Disable right click menu on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to build a minesweeper game with php and jquery. This means I want the user to be able to right-click elements to mark areas as a potential bomb or a questionmark. Now I have the right click event and the code works, however if I don't alert anything I get the menu with inspect element etc. I've tried throwing in some return false's but they haven't helped. How can I stop the menu appearing on right-click?

```
$('.overlay').mousedown(function(event) {
switch (event.which) {
    case 1:
        //left click code
        break;
    case 3:
        theID = event.target.id;
        if ($('#'+theID).is(":visible") && $('.bomb_'+theID).css("visibility") == "hidden" 
        && $('.mystery_'+theID).css("visibility") == "hidden"){
            $('#'+theID).css("background", "none");
            $('.bomb_'+theID).css("visibility", "visible");
            alert("x");
        }else if($('.bomb_'+theID).is(":visible")){
            $('.bomb_'+theID).css("visibility", "hidden");
            $('.mystery_'+theID).css("visibility", "visible");
            alert("y");
        }else{
            $('.mystery_'+theID).css("visibility", "hidden");
            $('#'+theID).css("background", "#fff");
            alert("z");
        }
        break;
}
});
```

Have tried to add event.preventDefault(); under the mousedown function but this doesn't change anything. Also tried it under case 3:.

Also return false; and event.stopImmediatePropagation(); don't work.

Comment: prevent the default action of the right mouse button with event.preventDefault

Comment: Thanks for your comment, unfortunately it hasn't helped. I tried putting it under case 3: which didn't work, as well  as under $('.overlay').mousedown ~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this via the context menu event?

```
$(".overlay").on("contextmenu",function(e){
   ....
   e.stopImmediatePropagation();
   e.preventDefault();
   return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks, both return false; and preventDefault(); work for me though stopImmediatePropagation(); doesn't.

Comment: @JakeRowsell it doesn't stop it, but it prevents other event listeners  running in Javascript from handling it. You properly don't have other listeners anyway so it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try `event.preventDefault()`;

Comment: Tried to add that below this: $('.overlay').mousedown(function(event) {
but it didn't make any difference.